# Is this a dracaena?

Tags: identification

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what this plant is. Is this some type of dracaena? I appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this looks very much like *Dracaena*. I would say *Dracaena deremensis*, [here](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-d-deremensis-at-home-1902752) is an overview for care instructions. They are not so difficult, watering too much is often the most tricky part (the tips of the leafs will become brown when watering too much).